# Is BouncyCastle provided in Android prior to Gingerbread?

Tags: android, bouncycastle, android-2.3-gingerbread

If so, in what versions is it available?  I only see it go as far back as Gingerbread here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bouncycastle/
Was it packaged under a different repository prior to GB?

Comment: Bouncy Castle is "available" in precisely zero versions of Android, insofar as it is not part of the Android SDK. It definitely was available in earlier versions than Gingerbread -- AFAIK, it was included back in Android 1.0. However, the fact that it is not part of the SDK, and that they got rid of a bunch of stuff from Bouncy Castle itself, is why somebody created Spongy Castle as a workaround: https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks Mark. I'll definitely look into Spongy Castle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it was moved from libcore/security/ in pre-Gingerbread to external/ in Gingerbread+:

https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/libcore/security/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/?repo=platform--dalvik&name=android-2.2_r1.3&r=dfd0afbcb08b871e224a28ecb4ed427a7693545c

to

https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse?repo=platform--external--bouncycastle

Answer (score 3):

See above for why it's not 'available'. If you need crypto, etc. functionality use the JCE interfaces (`Cipher`, `Signature`, etc.) and your app will work on all versions that have a provider for the particular mechanism/algorithm (it is not necessarily Bouncy Castle, especially in newer versions). If you need BC specific, lower level APIs (ASN.1 parsing, etc.), bundle Spongy Castle in your app and use that.

Comment: +1 for Spongy Castle here's the githib repo https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle